# strange behavior for validation dataset loss and accuracy

Tags: deep-learning, lstm

I'm training an LSTM model for a binary classification and using validation_split = 0.2 (in Keras), I see the following curves for the loss and accuracies of the train and test datasets. Here are two questions:

1. Why for epoch < 10, the loss of the test dataset is much smaller than that of the training dataset and also its accuracies much higher?
2. At epoch around 80 the curves for the train and test dataset losses converge whereas their accuracies don't. Does it mean that the model is still underfitting?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Just to say that I'm also puzzled by these curves, I can't think of any explanation. You're sure you didn't swap the curves right? The only thing I can say is that underfitting wouldn't make the test set performance higher than the training set performance.